# How can I remove a label strike out effect

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, label

I will write a todo list and the item label should be strike out when its done and removed on undone. The strike out on click works, but I can't remove it when its already strike out. My approaches were to RemoveAttribute on NSMutableAttributedString or maybe to redraw the whole label.

```
[assembly:ResolutionGroupName(OvanTasks.LabelStrikeOutEffect.EffectNamespace)]
[assembly: ExportEffect(typeof(LabelStrikeOutEffect), nameof(LabelStrikeOutEffect))]
namespace OvanTasks.iOS
{
   public class LabelStrikeOutEffect : PlatformEffect
   {
       public LabelStrikeOutEffect()
       {
       }

       protected override void OnAttached()
       {
          SetStrikeOut(true);
       }

       protected override void OnDetached()
       {
          SetStrikeOut(false);
       }

       protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs args)
       {
           base.OnElementPropertyChanged(args);

           if (args.PropertyName == Label.TextProperty.PropertyName || args.PropertyName == Label.FormattedTextProperty.PropertyName)
           {
               SetStrikeOut(true);
           }
       }

    private void SetStrikeOut(bool strikeout)
    {
        try
        {
            var label = (UILabel)Control;
            var text = (NSMutableAttributedString)label.AttributedText;
            var range = new NSRange(0, text.Length);


            if (strikeout)
            {
                text.AddAttribute(UIStringAttributeKey.StrikethroughStyle, NSNumber.FromInt32((int)NSUnderlineStyle.Single), range);
            }
            else
            {
                Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => {
                    text.RemoveAttribute(UIStringAttributeKey.StrikethroughStyle, range);   
                });
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Cannot strike out Label. Error: " + ex.Message.ToString());
        }
        finally {
            Control.SetNeedsDisplay();
        }
    }

  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I have a solution. I just override the AttributedText of the label with new attributes.

```
if (strikeout)
{
   var newText = new NSMutableAttributedString(text.Value);
   newText.AddAttribute(UIStringAttributeKey.StrikethroughStyle, NSNumber.FromInt32((int)NSUnderlineStyle.Single), range);
   label.AttributedText = newText;
}
else
{
    var newText = new NSMutableAttributedString(text.Value);
    label.AttributedText = newText;
}
```